# Model properties not set when returning to the controller for post

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, vb.net-2010, telerik-editor

I'm going blind staring at this. When I click save on the view, the model being sent to the save method of the controller has no values set, they're all default values. 
What am I missing? I'm actually using the exact same technique from another project...
The data is populated just fine in my view, I can edit it and click save, the code enters the SetSiteTerms method in the controller but has none of the data from the view. :-(
I know this is something simple and dumb but I just can't see it yet.

Model:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

<KnownType(GetType(SiteToA))> _
Public Class SiteToA

    <ScaffoldColumn(False)> _
    Public Property ID As Integer = 0
    Public Property AgreementHTML As String = String.Empty
    Public Property AgreementName As String = String.Empty
    Public Property IsActive As Boolean = False

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

View:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl(Of Community_Portal_Admin.SiteToA)" %>
<% Using Html.BeginForm("SetSiteTerms", "SiteToA", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "SiteTermsForm"})%>


    <div class="gridFrame">
        <% Html.Telerik().EditorFor(Function(m) m.AgreementHTML) _
                    .Name("AgreementHTML") _ ' Name must be the same as the property name in the model
                    .Encode(True) _
                    .HtmlAttributes(New With {.style = "height:300px;"}) _
                    .Render()%>
        <br />
        <div class="smallFrameLeft">        
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Home", Nothing, New With {.class = "t-button", .Style = "font-size:12px;"})%>
        </div>
        <div class="smallFrameRight">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="t-button" />       
        </div>
    </div>
<% End Using%>
```

Controller:

```
Imports Telerik.Web.Mvc

Public Class SiteToAController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim setting As SiteToA
        Try
            setting = SiteToARepository.One(Function(d) d.IsActive = True)
            ViewData.Model = setting
            Return PartialView()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function

    <HttpPost()> _
    Function SetSiteTerms(ByVal model As SiteToA) As ActionResult
        Dim setting As SiteToA
        Try
            setting = SiteToARepository.One(Function(d) d.ID = model.ID)
            TryUpdateModel(setting)
            If Not SiteToARepository.Update(setting) Then Throw New Exception("There was a problem during update")
            Return PartialView()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return PartialView()
        Finally
            If Not setting Is Nothing Then
                setting.Dispose()
                setting = Nothing
            End If
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

EDIT:
I've updated my view and controller. Any ideas why my model is populated, can be editing in the view but when I post with the save button, the model sent to the controller has no data???

Comment: Is there no help to be had out there for this? It's got to be something simple. Racking my brain here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the orginal post to show the answer provided by Telerik, also my problem with the rest of the model was a silly missing : lol